# Can't publish facebook instant article in development mode

Tags: laravel, facebook

For some reason, I can't publish articles using custom CMS solution we have made in Laravel. The developer which made this does not work with us anymore, and client requested to change the facebook page. He used this SDK: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-instant-articles-sdk-php

New Facebook page needs to go through verification for instant article.

So, when I set development_mode=false, I get the error "This page has not been accepted in the review process for publishing Instant Articles yet", which is fine, that error is expected.

But, when I change to development_mode=true, nothing happens, no errors. The request went without errors, but article was not published in the Development Articles.

Any idea what might be the problem here?

Comment: The downvotes are likely due to many reasons: Not including the code in question, not including well formatted error logs, asking others to take wild guesses as to what's gone wrong between your CMS, Laravel Settings, and the FB SDK. Just a guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I don't appreciate negative down-votes, since this was not the problem with the code, the solution for this problem was manually posting first 10 articles. No matter what, SDK could not publish anything, nor in development nor in production mode, until I published 10 articles manually.